# is it good to use Session for storing a logged in user id? Or is there a simpler way?

Tags: asp.net, webforms

We have a log-in form in ASP.Net Webforms. and when user logs in we save the user id to session state.

```
Session["CurrentUserId"] = user.Id;
```

So this is how we know a user is logged in.

```
if(Session["CurrentUserId"] == null) Redirect("Login.aspx");
```

This is all we use Session for. I am storing session in DynamoDB because we have many load balanced servers. But sometimes DynamoDB gets overloaded or gives errors. So I trying to get rid of session state to avoid these errors and to simplify a login process.

So what alternatives are there? How do modern websites log people in and remember they are logged in, and timeout after x minutes?

Is there a way to use a secure cookie to just do it? And how would you expire it if user doesnt do anything for 20 minutes? It has to work over a collection of web servers.

Comment: Session is a huge bottleneck when not done properly (i.e. the plain vanilla way you are using it) as the Session object is locked for read or writes, meaning each request has to wait to get a hold of the Session for that user. Done properly, it is a pain to manage. Have you considered an auth cookie?

Answer (score 0):

Storing user ID in session is not necessarily bad but has to be combined with other things in order to secure the site against things like [session fixation attack](https://owasp.org/www-community/attacks/Session_fixation#:%7E:text=The%20session%20fixation%20attack%20is,before%20the%20user%20logs%20in.) and [CSRF (also known as "session riding")](https://owasp.org/www-community/attacks/csrf). It is also problematic in a web farm if you are using in-proc session state.

In ASP.NET web forms, the standard way to authenticate is to use [forms authentication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/older-versions-security/introduction/an-overview-of-forms-authentication-cs), which places an encrypted cookie ("authentication ticket") on the browser. You may also want to put the user ID somewhere in session and compare it to the authentication ticket in order to ensure they match.

Answer (score 0):

if you using the standard FBA login providers?

You can get user logon ID with this:

```
 Membership.GetUser.ProviderUserKey
```

And you can get user email with this:

```
 Membership.GetUser.Email
```

So, the user logon id can be fetched with above.

As for session() being a bottle neck?

Well, it not all that bad - you not "updating" the session() value by doing this, so it certainly does not have to be written back each time (for a post) and also it means that a lock on session() during post backs etc. should not occur.

I would however consider one of the above two approaches, since then session() re-sets or anything else would not matter to get the user ID, or email.

As noted, this much depends on what security and authentication provider you are using here.

Comment: im not using any security or authentication provider. its basically, compare user/pass with my own database. if success, add the username to session. thats it. what would a "security and authentication provider" offer in such a simple process?

Comment: Boatloads of features. First up, you can secure any page - zero code. If a user hits a page without having logged in, then IIS will intercept, ask for logon, and THEN CONTINUE on to the page where the user was going. And you can secure web pages by "role", and again zero code for you. So, you can make a folder and say ONLY salesGroup people (only those who are a member of SalesGroup) can use those web pages in that folder. I mean, you might want to assing a user Admin, SalesGroup, and PortalMaster. Using the built in security system means you get all this ability - and ZERO code required.

Comment: I mean, in most cases, it not hard to setup basic security - and the user names are in a table. And not only that, you can then drop in a asp.net logon control - once again, just a control And then you can check/test with built in features to get their "pk "ID", and even email. And even the page for them to re-set their password - all done for you. And even a check box [x] - remember me - (and the browser will - again, all automatic for you, and all without code).  I mean, to secure a bunch of report pages? You don't have to write one line of code. And unlike your code - its actually secure.

Comment: And yes, once it setup, then the code is MUCH more simple. but, yes, it DOES have a learning curve - no question about it. But, for that extra work, you get huge beneifts. And sure, if you just have a few pages? The rolling a logon like you have is ok. But, if the site is to grow, and you want a good security model - one that you can manage over time, then adopting security really is a good idea. Once it is setup, then coding and using features like say some users are members of a give "role"? It really a whole lot easier. This is like anything - yes some additonal setup time is required.